# Angular 6 check for the existence of a variable with ngIf

Tags: loops, angular6, ngfor, angular-ng-if

How can I check for the existence of a value in angular 6 with ngIf in a nested json object?
I have this Json returned from an api call:

```
 {

 "orth": ["axxam"],

 "gram":[
      {"pos": ["isem"],
       "feminine": ["taxxamt"],
       "plural":"ixxamen"}
        ]
  }
```

I managed to get the values for "orth" and "pos". What I cannot get is this: I want first to test if the pos == isem, if and only if this is true, then I will show the values for "feminine" and "plural".
Here is the code so far:

```
 <span> spelling: {{elements?.orth}}</span> 
 <span> POS: {{elements?.gram[0].pos}}</span>
```

The following is not working:

```
  <span *ngIf="elements?.gram[0].pos===isem"> POS: 
 {{elements?.gram[0].feminine}}</span>
```

Additionally, can I loop through the object?
I tried this with no results:

```
 <span *ngFor="let element of elements.gram | keyvalue">
  {{element.key}}: {{element.value}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close.  :)

In the first `<span>` that is not working, `elements?.gram[0].pos` is actually an array, so should be referenced like this: `elements?.gram[0].pos[0]`.  Also to compare a string you need to enclose the string in quotes, as you wrote it the code will attempt to compare `elements?.gram[0].pos` to a variable named `isem`.  Put those together and it would look like this:

```
<span *ngIf="elements?.gram[0].pos[0]==='isem'"> 
    POS: {{elements?.gram[0].feminine}}
</span>
```

For your loop, `elements?.gram` is an array with only one element, which is an object - that object contains three elements.  If you want to iterate through the object that is inside the array, specify your `*ngFor` like this:

```
<span *ngFor="let element of elements?.gram[0] | keyvalue">
    {{element.key}}: {{element.value}}
</span>
```

Here is a [Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53662787?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) showing this in action.

I hope this helps.